# Cordova: get the filename from the intent

Tags: cordova, android-intent, gmail, cordova-plugins

I'm able to open files in the Cordova app using the Android intents.

it's a piece of cake to get the filename from the `intent.data` URL when the filename sits at the end:

`content://com.Slack.fileprovider/slack_files/AAA.TXT` or `content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/root_files/storage/6794-1D06/AAA.TXT`

from the Gmail app, however, I'm getting something like:
`content://com.google.android.gm.sapi/XXX@gmail.com/message_attachment_external/%23thread-a%3Ar-5057787201526387426/%23msg-a%3Ar-7956362123961253525/0.1?account_type=com.google&mimeType=application%2Foctet-stream&rendition=1`

how can I get the file name from the url like this? is it posible in Cordova?

there is also the `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(intent.data, function (fileEntry) ....` where the `fileEntry` doesn't contain any useful information either.